# Android: Read an external file (not created by app)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, io, filesystems

We are creating an Android app (game) using Unity.

in order to deal with Android we wrote an Android Library Module.

we want to insert a text file to the Android file system manually, and than access it through the app, where should we put the file and how can we access it?

we tried

```
File file = new File(context.getExternalFileDir(null), "fileToRead.txt");
System.out.println(file.toString());
```

while the file "fileToRead.txt" is in sd_card/Android/data/com.ourapp.ourapp/

with no success.
(file.exists() returns false).

edit:
we added these to the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

i also

Comment: Did you put in your manifest the permission needed to read and write files to external storage?

Comment: yeah we added these:

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: What do you mean with inserting a textfile manually? Where? How? When?

Answer (score 3):

Go to your **Player settings**, for Android, Change **Write access** from "**Internal Only**" to **External (SDCard)**. You can then use `Application.persistentDataPath` to get the location of your **external storage** path.

```
string myPath = Application.persistentDataPath;
```

It will return something like this:
'`/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/' + package-name + '/files'`;

You can then manipulate it to point to your custom file directory or use it like that.

```
File file = new File(myPath, "fileToRead.txt");
System.out.println(file.toString());
```

EDIT:
Try this simple method from **Unity Website**. It removes the need of Java Module or code.

```
    string getPath()
    {
        string path = "";
#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
 try {
          IntPtr obj_context = AndroidJNI.FindClass("android/content/ContextWrapper");
          IntPtr method_getFilesDir = AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID(obj_context, "getFilesDir", "()Ljava/io/File;");

          using (AndroidJavaClass cls_UnityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer")) {
             using (AndroidJavaObject obj_Activity = cls_UnityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity")) {
                IntPtr file = AndroidJNI.CallObjectMethod(obj_Activity.GetRawObject(), method_getFilesDir, new jvalue[0]);
                IntPtr obj_file = AndroidJNI.FindClass("java/io/File");
                IntPtr method_getAbsolutePath = AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID(obj_file, "getAbsolutePath", "()Ljava/lang/String;");   

                path = AndroidJNI.CallStringMethod(file, method_getAbsolutePath, new jvalue[0]);                    

                if(path != null) {
                   Debug.Log("Got internal path: " + path);
                }
                else {
                   Debug.Log("Using fallback path");
                   path = "/data/data/*** YOUR PACKAGE NAME ***/files";
                }
             }
          }
       }
       catch(Exception e) {
          Debug.Log(e.ToString());
       }
#else
        path = Application.persistentDataPath;
#endif
        return path;
    }
```

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/283823/how-can-you-save-both-internally-and-externally.html

Comment: the player settings are already set that way. i'll try the different syntax to get the path. thx.

Comment: Modified by answer. Application.persistentDataPath should work. If not, try the other function.

Comment: can't find Application.persistentDataPath (won't compile)

Comment: also, i need to handle the file in java environment to use some java features such as regular expressions and such.

Comment: This is Unity3D right?You are suppose to do that from Unity. It compiles on my side. It does compile.What Unity3D version? Update the code you have in your question. Here is the document Unity website http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html

Comment: another great answer

Comment: Thanks Joe. @ErezLevanon, There is a regular expression in C# too. It is unnecessary to do this in Java. The two solution I provided should work. If you insist you must do this from Java, then you can call this C# function from Java with UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("guiText", "getPath", "").  For more information on this, go here http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/android-plugin-call-c-from-java.78598/

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "fileToRead.txt");
if (!file.exists()) {
    try {
        file.createNewFile();  
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
System.out.println(file.toString());
```

You have to add the permission to your manifest too:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` already includes `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. So if you added a permission for writing, you can read as well. Thus you can delete `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Comment: hey, this syntax creates a new empty file somewhere but doesn't really access the file that i put on the device manually.

Comment: dont you need to create it before access? how do you put it there before?

Comment: I wan't to access files that were put there by the user manually

Comment: what does return System.out.println(file.toString()); in your case? 
sd_card/Android/data/com.ourapp.ourapp/fileToRead.txt ?

Comment: what you can also check is which permissions your file has. Others should can read it too

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.ourapp.ourapp/files/fileToRead.txt

Comment: the file is readable writable and not hidden. are these the permissions you talked about?

Comment: and you put the file manually in this folder, right? /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.ourapp.ourapp/files/

Comment: on the device it looks like this:
sd_card/Android/Data/com.ourapp.ourapp/files/

Comment: if you create a new file via code, as i suggested above (with some other name). Does this new file appear near your file, which you put there manually? Is it the same folder?

Comment: it does not apeare there

Comment: well then it is the wrong folder. You should put you custom files in the app's folder (/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.ourapp.ourapp/files/)

Comment: yeah but i can't find it on the devide.. :\

Comment: install Total Commander for managing your file system https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander